# I am trying to scrape multiple tables from 30 similar links using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have 10 links of companies.

```
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/ASHRAFI-MEDIA-NETWORK-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22120GJ2019PTC111757,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/METTLE-PUBLICATIONS-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22120MH2019PTC329729,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/PRINTSCAPE-INDIA-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22120MH2020PTC335354,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/CHARVAKA-TELEVISION-NETWORK-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22121KA2019PTC126665,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/BHOOKA-NANGA-FILMS-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130DL2019PTC353194,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/WHITE-CAMERA-SCHOOL-OF-PHOTOGRAPHY-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130JH2019PTC013311,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/RLE-PRODUCTIONS-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130KL2019PTC059208,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/CATALIZADOR-MEDIA-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130KL2019PTC059793,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/TRIPPLED-MEDIAWORKS-OPC-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130MH2019OPC333171,
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/KRYSTAL-CINEMAZ-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130MH2019PTC330391
```

Now I am trying to scrape tables from these links and save the data in csv columns in well manner formet. I want to scrape tables of "Company Details", "Share Capital & Number of Employees", "Listing and Annual Compliance Details", "Contact Details", "Director Details". If any table has not the data or if any column is missing I want that column blank in output csv file. I have written a code but can't get the output. I am doing something wrong here. Please help

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import csv
import lxml

url_file = "Zaubalinks.txt"

with open(url_file, "r") as url:
    url_pages = url.read()
# we need to split each urls into lists to make it iterable
pages = url_pages.split("\n") # Split by lines using \n

# now we run a for loop to visit the urls one by one
data = []
for single_page in pages:
    r = requests.get(single_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

    table = soup.find_all('table')  # finds all tables
    table_top = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]  # the top table

    try:  # try to get the other table if exists
        table_capital = pd.read_html(str(table))[5]
        table_listing = pd.read_html(str(table))[6]
        table_contact = pd.read_html(str(table))[7]
        table_director = pd.read_html(str(table))[8]
    except:
        table_capital = pd.DataFrame()
        table_listing = pd.DataFrame()
        table_contact = pd.DataFrame()
        table_director = pd.DataFrame()

    result = pd.concat([table_top, table_capital, table_listing, table_contact, table_director])
    data.append(result)
    print(data)
    pd.concat(data).to_csv('ZaubaAll.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

companies = {
    'ASHRAFI-MEDIA-NETWORK-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22120GJ2019PTC111757',
    'METTLE-PUBLICATIONS-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22120MH2019PTC329729',
    'PRINTSCAPE-INDIA-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22120MH2020PTC335354',
    'CHARVAKA-TELEVISION-NETWORK-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22121KA2019PTC126665',
    'BHOOKA-NANGA-FILMS-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130DL2019PTC353194',
    'WHITE-CAMERA-SCHOOL-OF-PHOTOGRAPHY-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130JH2019PTC013311',
    'RLE-PRODUCTIONS-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130KL2019PTC059208',
    'CATALIZADOR-MEDIA-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130KL2019PTC059793',
    'TRIPPLED-MEDIAWORKS-OPC-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130MH2019OPC333171',
    'KRYSTAL-CINEMAZ-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22130MH2019PTC330391'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        goal = []
        for company in companies:
            r = req.get(url.format(company))
            df = pd.read_html(r.content)
            target = pd.concat([df[x].T for x in [0, 3, 4]], axis=1)
            goal.append(target)
        new = pd.concat(goal)
        new.to_csv("data.csv")


main("https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/{}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your. While I am runing this code I am getting data from tables 0, 3 and 4 index. I also need 7th table on this page. but while I am putting 7 I am getting error. I am new in this, please help in this. Also I need this unstructured csv file structured fomet. How can I do this? Your help in this will be a great pleasure for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: waiting for your reply. I need 5 tables of -  
"Company Details", 
"Share Capital & Number of Employees", 
"Listing and Annual Compliance Details",
"Contact Details",
"Director Details".

Answer (score 0):

Fortunatley, it seems you can get there with simpler methods. Taking one reandom link as an example, it should be something like:

```
url = 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/CHARVAKA-TELEVISION-NETWORK-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U22121KA2019PTC126665'

import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html(url)
```

From here, your tables are in `tables[0]`, `tables[3]`, `tables[4]`, `tables[15]`, etc. Just use a `for` loop to rotate through all the urls.

Comment: did not understand can you please elaborate. I am new in this.

Comment: @SumitJha - The sample url (and presumably others) keep the data in various tables (19, on this particular page). Pandas just loads these tables by directly reading the page. So, for example, the table `Companies with Similar Address` is in `tables[15]`. So if you enter `tables[15]` - the output should be that table.

Comment: Understand, Thanks for the reply. I am trying to get the data of table 0,3,4,7. And need this data in csv in well manner formet but I am not getting the result. Any help would be great for me.

Comment: @SumitJha Fortunately, that's also simple. For example: `tables[3].to_csv('file_name.csv')`.